# Django Channels; ECHO example doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Consumers file

```
def ws_message(message):
    # ASGI WebSocket packet-received and send-packet message types
    # both have a "text" key for their textual data.
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })
```

Routing file

```
from channels.routing import route
from myapp.consumers import ws_message

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message),
]
```

What I'm running.

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/chat/");
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
}
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("hello world");

if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) socket.onopen();
```

It does nothing at all. I've seen other issues like this and they all said to downgrade twisted to 16.2. Well I did that but then runserver started to give me can't import IProtocol--- issues. Is there a fix to this, or should I just not use channels, and try something else?

Comment: are u using redis server?

Comment: @amrit  That is correct. I've tried to rest of the examples on their page and the only reason I think this does not work is because of lack of a connect consumer, with accept:True, and maybe the lack of a disconnect consumer. I'm not completely sure, but this is just my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `consumers.py` file add following methods...

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):


    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    room = message.content['path'].strip("/")
    message.channel_session['room'] = room
    Group("chat-%s" % room).add(message.reply_channel)

@channel_session
def ws_message(message):
Group("chat-%s" % message.channel_session['room']).send(content={
            'text': json.dumps({
                'message': message.content['text'],
                'data': hi,
            # "text": message['text'],
            # "text": str(serializers.data),
            })  })

@channel_session_user
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chat-%s" % message.channel_session['room']).discard(message.reply_channel)
```